# Get image width height javascript

Tags: javascript, image, height, width

Well, I have this code:

http://jsfiddle.net/hv9gB/3/

```
    (function() {

    var img = document.getElementById('my_image');

    // Original
    var width, height;

    // Display
    var d_width = img.width;
    var d_height = img.height;

    var updateDetail = function() {
        document
            .getElementById('display_size')
            .innerHTML = 'Display Size: ' + d_width + ' x ' + d_height;

        document
            .getElementById('native_size')
            .innerHTML = 'Original Size: ' + width + ' x ' + height;
    };

    // Using naturalWidth/Height
    if (img.naturalWidth) {
        width = img.naturalWidth;
        height = img.naturalHeight;

        updateDetail();
    } else {
        // Using an Image Object
        img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            width = this.width;
            height = this.height;

            updateDetail();
        };
        img.src = 'http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-640-480-3.jpg';
    }

}());
```

And that is my site:

http://dhems.x10.mx/

But on my site isn't working show the width and height of image

Why?!?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put your code in

```
window.onload = function() {
 //insert code here
}
```

Your js file is executed before the engine reach the picture..You're getting the following console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
```

It's also a good practice to put all scripts files in the end of the page and all css files in the begin. It will increase the loading time of your page, because if JS files are in the begin, your browser won't start to render until these files are downloaded.

your code should look like:

```
window.onload = function() {

var img = document.getElementById('my_image');

// Original
var width, height;

// Display
var d_width = img.width;
var d_height = img.height;

var updateDetail = function() {
    document
        .getElementById('display_size')
        .innerHTML = 'Display Size: ' + d_width + ' x ' + d_height;

    document
        .getElementById('native_size')
        .innerHTML = 'Original Size: ' + width + ' x ' + height;
};

// Using naturalWidth/Height
if (img.naturalWidth) {
    width = img.naturalWidth;
    height = img.naturalHeight;

    updateDetail();
} else {
    // Using an Image Object
    img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        width = this.width;
        height = this.height;

        updateDetail();
    };
    img.src = 'http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-640-480-3.jpg';
}

}
```

Comment: yeah, just put your code in window.onload = function () { code here }

Comment: You're welcome. By the way consider marking the best answers as ANSWERED, so the other people won't get in here for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

Move the script tag after the image in HTML. Script gets executed before the image goes into page.

Comment: Did you look at the script? `window.onload = function() {`

Comment: `var img = document.getElementById('my_image');` isn't in onload

Answer (score 0):

Put the code at the bottom of your `<body>` in a `<script type='text/javascript'>` or use `window.onload`. If you have other things loading `onload` the first option is your best choice, otherwise use this code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  (function(){
    var pre = window.onload;
    onload = function(){
      if(pre)pre();
      //other code here
    }
  })();
</script>
```

This example can be used in your `<head>`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! but I wanted the code on .js file to I learn :D

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function readImage(file) {

    var reader = new FileReader();
    var image  = new Image();

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);  
    reader.onload = function(_file) {
        image.src    = _file.target.result;              // url.createObjectURL(file);
        image.onload = function() {
            var w = this.width,
                h = this.height,
                t = file.type,                           // ext only: // file.type.split('/')[1],
                n = file.name,
                s = ~~(file.size/1024) +'KB';
            $('#uploadPreview').append('<img src="'+ this.src +'"> '+w+'x'+h+' '+s+' '+t+' '+n+'<br>');
        };
        image.onerror= function() {
            alert('Invalid file type: '+ file.type);
        };      
    };

}
$("#choose").change(function (e) {
    if(this.disabled) return alert('File upload not supported!');
    var F = this.files;
    if(F && F[0]) for(var i=0; i<F.length; i++) readImage( F[i] );
});
</script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Multiple image upload with preview by Roko C.B.</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="file" id="choose" multiple="multiple" />
<br>
<div id="uploadPreview"></div>
</body>
</html>
```