# Getting width from hidden image with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I have in my HTML an image (id=”stone”) which I hide. From this image I make later several copies (id=”stone_xxx) in JS with cloneNode, put them in the DOM and remove the hidden-class. Everything works all right. I need the width initially at program start (before I make the first copy) so I take it from the hidden image (id=”stone”). But I always get the naturalHeight (90px) and not the actual height (45px).
I even tried it in the console to exclude that perhaps CSS is executed after JS but this didn`t change anything, so I had to use window.onload like in [Get image width height javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255883/get-image-width-height-javascript).

```js
let stone = document.getElementById( "stone" );
let newStone = stone.cloneNode( false );
newStone.classList.remove( 'hidden' );
let i = 1;
newStone.id = "stone_" + i;
let el = document.getElementById( 'position_' + i);
el.prepend(newStone);

console.log(stone.naturalWidth);  // => 272
console.log(stone.width);         // => 272 Should be : 45
```

```css
.hidden { display: none;}
.stone { width: 45px;}
```

```html
<img id="stone" class="stone hidden" src=https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png />
<div id="position_1"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I solved it:** The browser doesn’t calculate the new dimensions of stone because of display none so the value of width isn´t recalculated. If I remove the class hidden everything is ok.
So I have 2 possibilities:
•   Starting without class hidden and setting it afterwards.
•   Get the width of one of the clones stones_xxx:

```
let newStone = document.getElementById( "stone_xxx" );
let width = newStone.width;
console.log(width);   // => 45
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img id="image" src="http://www.fillmurray.com/200/200" alt="image" />

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      const width = $('#image').width();

      console.log(width); // 200
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is not what I wanted. I asked to get the width from an image which is hidded and the size is changed through a css-rule from a class. You just deliver the width from an unchanged image which is the easy way.<br>
By the way if I put the code in JSFiddle than I got 200 as result but if I put it in a local HTML-file than I got 0 as result.